# Calculating and displaying variation of sub group responses within larger group

Tags: standard-deviation, standard-error, group-differences, percentage

I have a question with 3 possible answers (yes, no, unsure), and I have the responses of two groups. Group A and group B.

Group A has three sub-groups (A1, A2, A3),
Group B has two sub-groups (B1, B2)

I have the count of participants that selected each answer and percentage of the sample that selected each answer.

Sample sizes vary therefore I want to compare using percentages for clarity, using a cluster column which displays a column for each groups answers.

I want to add error bars showing the range of responses for each subgroup within the main group.

As I am comparing percentages, what measure should I use for the error bars? Is standard deviation suitable?

If not, is there any other you recommend?